# String building attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically selecting elements in jQuery, how can I make it more resilient?

```
$('[data-example="' + exampleData + '"]').each(...);
```

I'm concerned that the data might contain special characters.

Answer (score 4):

**Avoid string building jQuery selectors**. If your `exampleData` variable might contain special characters, or possibly contains user input, you've opened yourself to selector injection.

For example, if `exampleData` has a value of:

```
'"],body,[a="'
```

The computed selector becomes:

```
[data-example=""],body,[a=""]
```

which might cause unexpected behavior.

More typically, the selector will just fail outright, and your page or app will not work as expected.

---

Although jQuery calls itself the "write less, do more" library, this is a case where you'll need to write a bit more.

Instead of string building a single selector, use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('[data-example]').filter(function () {
  return $(this).data('example') === exampleData;
});
```